# Laravel Model Relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

What could be wrong with my model:

Connection table:

> id, parent_sid, connection_id (nullable)

Connection Step

> id, sid, date_started, date_ended, connection_id

Step

> id, name, url

```
class Step extends Eloquent {
    public function connections() {
        return $this->hasMany("Connection", "parent_sid");
    }
...}


class Connection extends Eloquent {
    public function connectionSteps() {
        return $this->hasMany("ConnectionStep", "connection_id");
    }
...}

class ConnectionStep extends Eloquent {
    public function connection() {
        return $this->belongsTo("Connection", "connection_id");
    }
... }
```

but when I run:

```
Step::find(1)->connections()->connectionSteps();
```

I always get this error:

> exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Call to undefined
>   method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::connectionSteps()'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your model with data from relationships you can do in this case:

```
$step = Step:with('connections.connectionSteps')->find(1);
```

Now you can display data this way:

```
echo $step->name;

foreach ($step->connections as $con) {
  foreach ($con->connectionSteps as $step)  {
     echo $step->date_started;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you! though everyone else has the same answer. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

In the example Step::find(1)->connections()->connectionSteps(),
you are thying to access relation connectionSteps of the Step which isn't defined.
That's why you get 'Call to undefined method ' as this is Connections relation.

You can achive this by using eager load which will load multiple relationships at one time:

```
Step::with(array('connections', 'connections.connectionSteps'))->find(1);
```

Hepe it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Correct way:

```
Step::find(1)->connections->connectionSteps;
```

For eager loading:

```
Step::with('connections.connectionSteps')->find(1)->connections->connectionSteps;
```